# Is the reason props in React shouldn't be changed/mutated is because React wants elements to be as predictable as possible?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, attributes, react-props

From React documentation.

> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept
>   arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing
>   what should appear on the screen.

Considering:

```
function Welcome(props) {   
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>; 
}
```

or

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Will give us the ability to do this:

```
<Welcome name="Luke" />;
<Welcome name="Leia" />;
```

to use as we wish in the DOM,

## Hello, Luke

## Hello, Leia

Now when people prescribe props shouldn't be changed, it would make sense the reason is in my thinking would be like the same as changing the values of attributes of an image tag?

HTML:

```
<img id="Executor" alt="Picture of Executor" src="/somepath/vaders-star-destroyer-executor.jpg"/>
```

JS:

Meanwhile in a Javascript file a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...

```
var imageOfVadersStarDestroyer = document.getElementById('Executor');

imageOfVadersStarDestroyer.src = "/somepath/vaders-star-destroyer-avenger.jpg"
```

Because if we keeping changing an elements attribute values this can cause confusion and slower renderings?

So is the reason why the prescription is to never change props in React is because is the library is trying to make elements as predictable as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting props outside of React is dangerous and should be avoided. Why? The main reason is that it doesn't trigger re-renders. Hence bugs and unexpected behaviour.

### Re-rendering

Most of the time, props are data that is store as state in the parent component, which is manipulated by calling `setState()` (or the second function returned by `React.useState()`). Once `setState()` is called, React re-renders and computes what has changed under the hood, with the latest props and state. Manually assigning values to props, therefore won't notify React that the data has changed and something has to be re-rendered.

### The good practice

Making props read-only allows React components to be as pure as possible, which is obviously a good practice anyway even when writing plain JS. Data won't be changed unexpectedly and can only be done so by calling `setState()` (You might have heard of the **single source of truth**, which is what React is trying to leverage).

Imagine you notice something went wrong in the app and the data shown to the end user is completely different from the source, it would be a pain trying to find out where the data has been manipulated wouldn't it? :)

Comment: This was what I was looking for! 

`The main reason is that it doesn't trigger re-renders.`

And when you mean:

`Manually assigning values to props, therefore won't notify React that the data has changed and something has to be re-rendered.`

You mean later on somewhere else? Because *passing* a value to a prop seems the point of them? Like what attributes are to `HTML`.

Comment: I meant you can technically modify props inside the component itself (or somewhere else, can’t think off the top of my head) but I’m sure that React will shout at you for doing that :) @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz

Answer (score 1):

> never change props in React

means that you should never do `this.props.name = "userName"` because of React's [one way data binding](https://hackernoon.com/data-flow-in-reactjs-c682edc95106), `props` are `read only`,  to update a component's props, you should pass a function from the parent that will do that ( in the parent ) , or dispatch an action if you're using redux, a change in the `props` will trigger a re-render

Answer (score 1):

`props` is a constant in this case. You will always need it in your components.
But there is a cleaner way to write it or even omit it.

#### Regular way with Function Expression 
(same as your exemple)

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

#### ES6 Object Destructing - explicit

```
function Welcome(props) {
  const {name} = pros
  return <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
}
```

#### ES6 Object Destructing - inplicit, cleaner way

```
function Welcome({name}) {
  return <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
}
```

And of course, you can use the class way which requires the usage of this.props.yourAttr
However, in the new version 3 of create-react-app, changed class components to functional components. You can see this exact modification on Github [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/e4fdac2418dbd1b3d51c8f0fecb474caa001f649#diff-9e2ecb03a0ec4155fbe42095c297a58e).

You can need to learn more about destructing assignment in the old and good MDN linked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) or an in-depth approach both array and object destructuring [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).